# When I press the button, I want the content of the text field to be added- IOS TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have updated my code,

everything seems good, but when i press the add button it does not add the table.

then i realized i have forgot to initialize array, then everything is ok

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "Hello_WorldAppDelegate.h"


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize tableView;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
// Add the following line if you want the list to be editable
// self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}


- (IBAction)addToTable:(id)sender{

 /*  
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Do you want to say hello?" message:@"More info..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Say  Hello",nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

*/

```
[myArray addObject:textField.text];
[self.tableView reloadData];

textField.text=@"";

/*
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}

[cell setText:[textField text]];

[self.tableView reloadData];
*/
}




- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return[myArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}

[cell setText:[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

// Set up the cell
return cell;
}


 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Navigation logic
}



// Override if you support editing the list
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
}   
/*if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}*/ 
}



/*
 Override if you support conditional editing of the list
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}
*/


/*
 Override if you support rearranging the list
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath  toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/


/*
 Override if you support conditional rearranging of the list
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   {
// Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
return YES;
}
 */ 


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
// Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}


- (void)dealloc {
[textField release];
[addButton release];
[super dealloc];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
[textField release];
textField = nil;
[addButton release];
addButton = nil;
[super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

ok i have solved my issue

thanks to everyone

Comment: You are calling addToTable as a class method? Because is defined as an instance method.
Try [self addToTable:] instead.

Comment: Check out my comment and try as I said.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is with your method name.

```
- (IBAction)addToTable:(id)sender:(UITableView *)tableView
```

change it like this

```
- (IBAction)addToTable:(id)sender
```

Comment: ok that fixed this but now another problem occurs;
i want to access the table inside the addToTable method, so i will be able to add the text of the textfields as a cell to the table

Comment: It looks like `RootViewController` is a subclass of `UITableViewController`. If so, then you can use like `self.tableView`. If not, then create an outlet for `UITableView` in `.h` file and connect to tableview in `Xib` file. Now you can access the `tableview`.

Comment: What is `self` here? A table view controller? Something to the effect of `[self tableView]`. Does `self` have a table view controller property? `[[self tableViewController] tableView]`. But, really: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a Q&A&Q&A&Q&A... site if you catch my drift.

Answer (score 0):

what you need, first use an array as a data source for a table then on click on the button you need to add the textField content into an array then reload the table.

so your button action look like

```
- (IBAction)addToTable:(id)sender
{
   [dataSouceArray addObject:yourTextField.text];
   [yourTable reloadData];

   yourTextField.text=@"";
}
```

and tableViewDelegate look like

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [yourDataSourceArray count];
}


  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero    reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}

[cell setText:[yourDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

// Set up the cell
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT(3.0)

@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {

yourarrayname.append(yourtextfield.text!)

yourtableview.reloadData()

}